# React-router deployed to Github Pages and the pages kept at the same position

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages

I deployed a react app with react-router to Github Pages. Clicking the bottom links and the position in another page would be also at the bottom.

With package `gh-pages` installed, this also happens in local dev server. Without the package, clicking a link to another page would be from the start.

Deployed work-in-progress project in Github Pages (best view with mobile browsers):
https://ymcheung.github.io/react-portfolio

Detailed code in StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/github/ymcheung/react-portfolio

I expect clicking the links and the position will be at the start.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the link you have to append id of div example:

http://www.page.com/about.html#info

Which #info is the div id of element that you would like to have position offet zero